# Template refresh stops jQuery event

Tags: jquery, meteor

In my Meteor App I built an edit function on a collection element. Therefore I have 2 states on every element; the normal view and an edit form. I used jQuery to have a nice slider effect, to switch between these two states.

```
Template.bookings.events
  'click .edit-booking': (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    bookingId = event.currentTarget.dataset.booking
    $('#booking-' + bookingId + '-data').slideToggle('slow')
    $('#booking-' + bookingId + '-form').slideToggle('slow')
```

This works fine. But in the callback function of the update I try to close the form again and there I have a problem.

```
  Meteor.call('updateBooking', {id: id, title: title, hours: hours},
             (error, booking) ->
               unless error
                 $.bootstrapGrowl "saved successfully", {align: 'center', type: 'success'}
                 $('#booking-' + id + '-data').slideToggle('fast')
                 $('#booking-' + id + '-form').slideToggle('fast')
                 booking
               else
                 $.bootstrapGrowl error.message, {align: 'center', type: 'error'}
                 error
             )
```

Somehow does the reactive refresh of my template stop the jquery event and I dont know how to implement this. I see the form closing for a splitsecond and then reopen again :)
The bootsrtapGrowl works fine.

Can anybody give me a hint. Thanks a lot.
Markus

Comment: hide(0) and show(0) does the trick ... toggle does not work, because it will be called twice.

Comment: If data is updated in your method updateBooking that is in your template that the form is in you will have the form being re-rendered. So what is happening is the form starts to slide closed and as it does meteor re-renders the form because some data was changed. I would suggest putting the div #booking-#-data out side the template that is re-rendered

Comment: This ist not posible, because after storing the data, it has to reload this part too .... but as i mentioned before .... it is a problem of the toggle event, which is called twice. I use specific toggleUp and toggleDown now, which does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to go off what you've given since the pieces of code causing the issues aren't given. I think it might be something to do with the template being re-rendered because it contains some reactive data that is being updated. So for this, in your HTML for `bookings` use an isolate around the data that is being updated

```
<template name="bookings">
    ...
    <div id="booking-xxx-yyyy">
        ....
        {{#isolate}}
            {{data}}
        {{/isolate}}
        ...
     </div>
    ...
</template>
```

What this does is everything inbetween `{{#isolate}}` will render on its own when its data changes, as if it were a subtemplate.

This way your whole template, including your html element with the `id="booking-..."` doesn't re-render so its animations are possible.

At the moment it looks like the animation starts, then the template re renders so the DOM is refreshed and JQuery loses track of the old animation.